How do you use HRTF for VLC?
I have a movie that is in 5.1 surround and I have some SHP2500 headphones. I want to use HRTF function of VLC to make the movie be like how it is intended be in straight of the action.
I tried reading the manual but couldn't find much. What is the correct way so I can enjoy the 5.1 in my stereo headphones?
I saw a filter about binaural filter but it's asking for a HRTF file. I assume it's not really needed but is there really a difference?
